# PostgreSQL output

Tags: bash, postgresql

I'm new to working with PostgreSQL and I'm running a PostgreSQL script from bash like this:

```
export PGSERVICEFILE=$HOME/.pg_service.conf
export PGSERVICE=dbalias
export PGUSER=username
export PGPASSWORD=password
psql <<EOF
do \$\$
begin
   for counter in 1..5 loop
      raise notice 'counter: %',counter;
   end loop;
end; \$\$
EOF
```

The output I receive looks like this:

```
NOTICE:  counter: 1
NOTICE:  counter: 2
NOTICE:  counter: 3
NOTICE:  counter: 4
NOTICE:  counter: 5
DO
```

I cannot explain the last line ("DO") and would like to get rid of it.

Comment: You are looking for the `-q` (quiet) flag: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you want to generate five number, using `select * from generate_series(1,5)` is much better

Comment: thank you. the -q flag does the trick.